# Using linebreak and other commands to customize vim indentation

Tags: indentation

I am using vim, by default I have not set the linebreak option in vim.So the following code:

```
aug =ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1,horizontal_flip=True,fill_mode="nearest")
```

is very long to fit in a single line in a window. So what I do is manually move and place the curser and then press enter resulting in:

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True,fill_mode="nearest")
```

which is more readable for me. Now when I set the linebreak option, I get

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,
height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True,fill_mode="nearest")
```

The code runs but is not comfortable to read, I would like to know is there any option in vim which automatically indents once the set linebreak option works.(i.e display the code like the 2nd one with proper indentation at the beginning of the second line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are called `:h 'breakindent'` and `:h 'breakindentopt'`. For example

```
let [&l:bri, &l:briopt] = [v:true, 'shift:'..shiftwidth()]
```

Note that all "linebreak"-related spaces are purely virtual. They are never written into a file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how should I use it, I have used `:set breakindent` but the line that follows is not intended. Where should I type the command you have given?

Comment: @Hrushi Shift value defaults to 0. For this reason you must set it with `breakindentopt` to see anything.

Comment: When I  `:set breakindentopt` [TAB] [TAB] I get a lot  options which are strings, also `:set breakindent [space] 4` doesn't work. Is this because I opened my file using vi file.py but I only have vim 8 installed

Comment: Where should I use this command `let [&l:bri, &l:briopt] = [v:true, 'shift:'..shiftwidth()]`, on my vimrc?

Comment: @Hrushi (1) Surely, it doesn't, as `bri` is **boolean** (2) And how did you do it with `linebreak`? Usually local options are overridden from `after/ftplugin`. There are at least several questions on this site with detailed explanations.

Comment: `set breakindentopt=shift:8 ` did the work, it was very silly of me not checking this site for its correct usage, anyways thank you

Comment: How about checking the help for the options?

Comment: I did that but it doesn't tell how to write the command. I am new to using commands in vim and thus didn't know,  anyhow was able to do it

Comment: @Hrushi `:help :set` or `:help :set-args` which is on the same page gives the `set` usage. Matt was being a bit "fancy" by given you one command that sets both options using list-unpacking and the fact that variables prefixed with `&` correspond to options. Certainly harder for a beginner to know!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful for me. Infact I was just now trying to change a parameter value and this command helped me